# Symmetry and the zeta function

Tags: functional-equations, riemann-zeta, riemann-hypothesis

It is an incontestable fact that symmetry is one of, if not the, most powerful tools a mathematician can have at his or her disposal. What I want to know, is if there are any good reasons as to why it has been neglected for over a century and a half in the analysis of the zeta function.

In his 1859 paper Riemann proved the functional equation for the zeta function, and defined the function:

$$\xi \left( {s} \right): = \frac{{\Pi \left( {\frac{s}{2}} \right)}}{{{\pi ^{\frac{s}{2}}}}}\left( {s - 1} \right)\zeta \left( s \right) = \frac{{\Pi \left( {\frac{{1 - s}}{2}} \right)}}{{{\pi ^{\frac{{1 - s}}{2}}}}}\left( { - s} \right)\zeta \left( {1 - s} \right)=\xi \left( {1 - s} \right)
$$

He then makes the change of variables $$s \mapsto 1/2 + s$$ and redefines the function as

$$\xi (s): =  - \frac{{\Pi \left( {\frac{{1/2 + s}}{2}} \right)}}{{{\pi ^{\frac{{1/2 + s}}{2}}}}}\left( {1/2 - s} \right)\zeta \left( {1/2 + s} \right) =  - \frac{{\Pi \left( {\frac{{1/2 - s}}{2}} \right)}}{{{\pi ^{\frac{{1/2 - s}}{2}}}}}\left( {1/2 + s} \right)\zeta \left( {1/2 - s} \right) = \xi \left( { - s} \right)
$$

And further establishes the product formula

$$\xi \left( s \right) = \xi \left( 0 \right)\prod\limits_{{\mathop{\rm Im}\nolimits} \left( \rho  \right) > 0} {\left( {1 - \frac{{{s^2}}}{{{\rho ^2}}}} \right)} 
$$

which shows that it behaves somewhat like the sine cardinal function, or more generally a Bessel function, except that its roots occur with logarithmic frequency.

The point is that, from the functional viewpoint at the very least, it is very unnatural to use the approach that has been used for the past century and a half for the same exact reason that we do not define, for some a, the function

$$f\left( s \right) = {\mathop{\rm sinc}\nolimits} (s + a)
$$

to be the primary definition of the function sinc. So, why would we do that for xi, or by consequence zeta?

Ironically, my own analysis suggests that in neglecting symmetry, the only possible proofs of the original Riemann Hypothesis are through exhaustive methods, which is highly counter-intuitive, but this is way beyond the scope of this post and likely anything that Riemann could have known.

Comment: "... a mathematician can have at his or her disposal".

Comment: Lol. See, when I was in elementary school, which is only about 15 years ago now, I was taught that the use of "his" naturally implied "his or hers" unless the context suggested otherwise. It used to be universally accepted. But it makes since that along with the modern push for political correctness and gender neutrality, such trivial conventions would be modified.

Comment: @justsomeguy90 http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_they

Comment: I think the people who wrote the books asserting that "his" naturally implied "his or her" were probably all male :) Seriously though, thank you for the change - there are plenty of forces pushing women away from mathematics, so every little bit to change that helps.

Comment: To the content of your question: the current definition of $\zeta$ has its symmetry centered at $s=1$, as you point out; this perhaps isn't as tidy as centering it at $s=0$, but I don't think it qualifies as "neglecting" that symmetry. And the traditional definition has certain tidiness that would be lost with a shift of variables - the primary one being that $\zeta(s) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty 1/n^s$ is the initial reason why the function was introduced.

Comment: Oh but it is! Consider sin(s). Making the change of variable from s to i*s, we have sinh(s). The current definition ignores symmetry because of the fact that the change of variable from s to i*s rotates the s-plane about the origin.

Comment: Plus, the point is that the sum that you mentioned and its equivalent Euler product are only equal to zeta for Re(s)>1.

Comment: Also, the product formula that I mentioned for xi, although similar to that for sinc, should still really be thought of as a formal product since we would wish to use it to analytically continue the Euler product into the critical strip.

Comment: I was really asking if there were any deeper reasons for the convention.